# Is there a preferred way to get the system time in cocos2d-x?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am writing a cross-platform application in Cocos2d-x.  I need to get the time to create a countdown clock to a certain time of day.  Since it is in C++, I can use time(...), mktime(...), and difftime(...) if I need to as a direct approach.

Is there a preferred method in Cocos2d-x for doing this in a cross-platform way (i.e. something built directly into the framework)?  I want the app to work the same on iPhones, iPads, and Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought this code would do the trick:

static inline long millisecondNow()
{
    struct cc_timeval now;
    CCTime::gettimeofdayCocos2d(&now, NULL);
    return (now.tv_sec * 1000 + now.tv_usec / 1000);
}

**HOWEVER**, only gives a part of what I need. In general, I need a real "date and time" object (or structure), not just the time of day in milliseconds.

The best solution, for now, seems to be using the "classic" localtime, mktime, difftime trifecta in C++.  I have a few examples below of some basic operations...I may cook up a general class to do these kinds of operations, but for now, these are a good start and show how to get moving:

```
double Utilities::SecondsTill(int hour, int minute)
{
   time_t now;
   struct tm target;
   double seconds;

   time(&now);  

   target = *localtime(&now);

   target.tm_hour = hour;
   target.tm_min = minute;
   target.tm_sec = 0;

   seconds = difftime(mktime(&target),now);

   return seconds;
}

DAYS_OF_WEEK_T Utilities::GetDayOfWeek()
{
   struct tm tinfo;
   time_t rawtime;
   time (&rawtime);

   tinfo = *localtime(&rawtime);

   return (DAYS_OF_WEEK_T)tinfo.tm_wday;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
time (&rawtime);
timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

CCLog("year------->%04d",timeinfo->tm_year+1900);
CCLog("month------->%02d",timeinfo->tm_mon+1);
CCLog("day------->%02d",timeinfo->tm_mday);

CCLog("hour------->%02d",timeinfo->tm_hour);
CCLog("minutes------->%02d",timeinfo->tm_min);
CCLog("seconds------->%02d",timeinfo->tm_sec);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
static inline long millisecondNow()
{
    struct cc_timeval now;
    CCTime::gettimeofdayCocos2d(&now, NULL);
    return (now.tv_sec * 1000 + now.tv_usec / 1000);
}
```

I used this function to get current time in millisecond. I am new in cocos2d-x so hope this can be helpful.

Comment: That seems close to what I am looking for.  I'll give a try and give feedback.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this lib, I just tested and it works fine.

https://github.com/Ghost233/CCDate

If you receive some wrong values, set timezoneOffset = 0;

Note: 0 <= month <= 11

Answer (score 0):

You can sheduleUpdate in clock class.

The update call with a float argument which is a delta time in seconds after last calls, this method is called every frame and cocos2d-x get time through from the system and count the delta.

Comment: Thanks.  While this is true, the question is not about scheduling the "check for the time", it is how to do the time request itself.  For example, in objective-C, there is an NSDate class just for handling date/time.  There is a DateTime class in C# for handling time.  Is there something equivalent in cocos2d-x?